# Fastest way to check if a list of sets has any containment relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, set

I hava a list of 10,000 random sets with different lengths:

```
import random

random.seed(99)
lst = [set(random.sample(range(1, 10000), random.randint(1, 1000))) for _ in range(10000)]
```

I want to know the fastest way to check if there is any set that is a subset of another set (or equivalently if there is any set that is a superset of another set). Right now I am using the following very basic code:

```
def any_containment(lst):
    checked_sets = []
    for st in lst:
        if any(st.issubset(s) for s in checked_sets):
            return True
        else:
            checked_sets.append(st)
    return False

%timeit any_containment(lst)
# 12.3 ms ± 230 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Clearly, my code is not utilizing previous information when checking containment in each iteration. Can anyone suggest the fastest way to do this?

Comment: I think the code you provide is not correct regarding the previous statement. It only check if a set is a subset of the previous one but not with the next ones. Thus the order matter in your code but not in the previous sentence. Check with `[{1}, {1,2}]` and `[{1,2}, {1}]` (this gives different results).

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Wow you are right. I think every pair of sets needs to be checked both for subset and superset.

Comment: I don't see how you would want to use "previous information". The only relation that would apply between sets *for this usecase* is that `a < b and b < c` implies `a < c` (though not even vice versa). However, since finding either of these is enough to terminate, there seems to be no *next* iteration that could use it.

Comment: @ShaunHan Yes, or alternatively you can test all combinations instead of item with only previous one. This should be twice slower in both cases but I think the former is simpler to optimize and understand.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For example they could build the *union* of all previous sets and first check the new `st` against that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be faster to sort by length and then try small sets as subset first (and for each, try large sets as superset first). Times in ms from ten cases, data generated like you did but without seeding:

```
agree yours   mine  ratio  result
True   2.24   2.98   0.75  True
True 146.25   3.10  47.19  True
True 121.66   2.90  41.91  True
True   0.21   2.73   0.08  True
True  37.01   2.82  13.10  True
True   5.86   3.13   1.87  True
True  54.61   3.14  17.40  True
True   0.86   2.81   0.30  True
True 182.51   3.06  59.60  True
True 192.93   2.73  70.65  True
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJBTsMwELznFXupGqMQmlZCCJErL@CGUGSSTWs1sS3bAfr6sBuHthFI@BJldma8O2t7Cgejdw/WjaPqrXEBnNSN6ZPWmR6C6lEFmCsNtnLoQsWoA@mncpIQDMapvdKySzsfxGMCdOoD1kdsKo/BQwmvbxPaGgeeHDUQMxL5qBakPqU@5Mr74Z00qReRzNxrL3FR8XEYBqfhxQ14xrHzuGRdG@TSWtQNXSaSK4dnSao4DbVS1UYHqXSPOlwN5bAnUOk9TeQpE2y4mMERT2WHOiPCBzqPJfcT7T8PqsOL8NIXp3KGc2tsKn7lAU8lhCmHKbMz/Z8QliOxvJrkUu8xLTazmjrnxXDYcem5l73tMJ15GRQbOiKb30TOH0V5zBUh4ooW3ozHVYcNufMTmefCL4s137h4LJFaLKkOPT00wv7aRFRsl4qA/F/ALV0bAcfAloFiAqzj1n@cy7mdDNar@3zbwhpuYAcrSAPeFLjLyGD@4l1wlEHki2QyG8dv)):

```
import random
from timeit import default_timer as time

def original(lst):
    checked_sets = []
    for st in lst:
        if any(st.issubset(s) for s in checked_sets):
            return True
        else:
            checked_sets.append(st)
    return False

def any_containment(lst):
    remaining = sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True)
    while remaining:
        s = remaining.pop()
        if any(s <= t for t in remaining):
            return True
    return False

for _ in range(10):
    lst = [set(random.sample(range(1, 10000), random.randint(1, 1000))) for _ in range(10000)]
    t0 = time()
    expect = original(lst)
    t1 = time()
    result = any_containment(lst)
    t2 = time()
    te = t1 - t0
    tr = t2 - t1
    print(result == expect, '%6.2f ' * 3 % (te*1e3, tr*1e3, te/tr), expect)
```

#### Improvement

The following seems further ~20% faster. Instead of first comparing the smallest set with potentially *all* larger sets before giving even just the *second*-smallest a chance, this does give other small sets an early chance.

```
def any_containment(lst):
    sets = sorted(lst, key=len)
    for i in range(1, len(sets)):
        for s, t in zip(sets, sets[-i:]):
            if s <= t:
                return True
    return False
```

Comparison with my old solution ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJBbsIwELznFXtB2CikJEhVhZprL732hhCyygasOo5lm7bp5@naDhDaSvUhkWdnZ2e0Nr0/dHr5YOzpJFvTWQ9W6F3XZo3tWvCyRelhqOywEUfltwG1IFwsZxnB8IxK9SVTzvNVBnQstkJqqfdQg6Nm3IViDm/Y1wp1ToR3tA7rF3tEHls@DlLhtTHphONI4wIXpjOMX2qyAaF75uCxBg9NZ@kr9ZXOrzLJlj9aDWFoNro/CeXGSapREofe/R0iuQgzZZwp9B5ZmQOVWOjio@GB5fJk7kuaWM@j9nouV5sfNilVSnQL/58gjNmOzCwGYbJNGdY0j6X9Fk60RiG7mC4XdHg@rL8IP6n9ucI5h1/aAd9Eeb8g9fAahs3gp8HXMHH0LhKxvCVadPSizsRqRKxuiR7DvYQ5zUqADUAVgDICxga/Z8F68JDDdHJfVA1MYQZLmADzOCtxSauwwx/vvKXgic@zKHY6fQM)):

```
agree  old    new   ratio  result
True   3.13   2.46   1.27  True
True   3.36   3.31   1.02  True
True   3.10   2.49   1.24  True
True   2.72   2.43   1.12  True
True   2.86   2.35   1.21  True
True   2.65   2.47   1.07  True
True   5.24   4.29   1.22  True
True   3.01   2.35   1.28  True
True   2.72   2.28   1.19  True
True   2.80   2.45   1.14  True
```

#### Yet another idea

A shortcut could be to first collect the union of all single-element sets, and check whether that intersects with any other set (either without sorting them, or again from largest to smallest after sorting). That likely suffices. If not, then proceed as previously, but without the single-element sets.

Comment: This compares the smallest set against the largest first, right?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes. And if that fails, the smallest vs second-largest, third-largest, etc. Maybe it would be better to give second-smallest a chance before having checked smallest against all others...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But I just checked and confirmed my initial guess: In 10 of 10 cases, the first set had only a single element and was already a subset of another set, ending the search.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Btw at first I considered to jokingly suggest simply `return True`. The likelihood seems very large. I had tested the smallest 100 sets and found that always around 20 to 40 of them were a subset of another.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect this to be the common path as well. Whether going through smallest or largest first is better probably depends on the data. Either way, sorting by length is a clever trick and nice approach!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Meh, sorting by length seems rather straightforward. Maybe the way of using it to compare extremes is a bit clever. Appended another way now, giving other small sets an early chance.